# Catch session id in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I wanna to know how to catch session id from device/client.

I have a Login API, the logic is like this. When client login to the apps they are also get an session id. the code is below:

```
public function user_post()
{
  $data = array (
    'username' => $this->input->get_post('username'),
    'password' => sha1($this->input->get_post('password'))
  );

  $result = $this->login_m->user_check($data);
  if ($result ) {
     foreach ($result as $row ) {

      $sess_array = array(
                  'username' => $row->username,
                  'email'    => $row->email,
                  'uniqueID' => $row->uniqueID,
                  'userid'   => $row->userid,
                  'session_id' => session_id()

                  );

      $this->session->set_userdata('logged', $sess_array);
      $this->response(array('success' => $this->session->userdata('logged') ));
    }
  } else {
    $this->response(array(404 => 'missing parameter'));
  }
}
```

it also has an array init. and the json response would like this below:

```
{
"success": {
"username": "johndoe123",
"email": "myemail@gmail.com",
"uniqueID": "1q2w3e4r5t6y",
"userid": "97",
"session_id": "1bbfdj07as68bvp3ctrboj8gs7"
}
}
```

the question is, how i to catch the session id that is store in client apps?

so, when they are trying to get some information like news, or their profile. The client apps send me back the session id.

I presume that session id has array data just like when they are try to login.
so maybe i will get the array, array value will be the condition to get the news or profile.

CMIIW

Comment: Why don't you use cookies ?

Comment: @blip how to do it? Im new in php

Answer (score 0):

```
$session_data=$this->session->userdata('logged');
```

use this to get all the session data  and you can get the particular data by iterating that array

like this `$session_data['session_id']`

Comment: hi @vicky,so the response after login will be like this `{ "success" : "1q2w33r3r3r3r3r3r3r" }`. so client will save the session. how iterate the array? i'm still confused. :-D when the client want to get some new, it will need an email also username.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->session->userdata('session_id');
```